# Volley server error

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on an Android app in which I am submitting some variables in url in order to save the data in database what ever user enter in the text fileds but I am unable to do so as I am getting an error called "*com.android.volley,Server error*".
I have tried many solutions on stack overflow like [use a variable in a URL object in android](http://Use%20a%20variable%20in%20a%20URL%20object%20in%20Android) and the other one [Volley server error with null network response](http://Volley%20Server%20Error%20with%20null%20Network%20response)
 bit it didn't solved my problem. Here is my sample code for registering url

```
 Context context;
EditText username, address, phoneNumber;
Button location, save;
String macAddress;

private final String REGISTER_URL = "http://www.zamakpk.com/sos/index.php/webservices_api/insert_user"+username+address+macAddress+phoneNumber;

public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_Address = "address";
public static final String KEY_PHONENO = "mobile";
public static final String KEY_MAC_ADDRESS = "mac";
```

And this is how I am registeing a user

```
private void registerUser() {
    final String usernameStr = username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String addressStr = address.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phoneNoStr = phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MAC_ADDRESS, macAddress);
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME, usernameStr);

            params.put(KEY_PHONENO, phoneNoStr);
            params.put(KEY_Address, addressStr);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Any idea what I am missing that I am unable to store user data in database and my server is working fine its working good on localhost.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It's always a great idea to include the error log.

Comment: `"http://www.zamakpk.com/sos/index.php/webservices_api/insert_user"+username+address+macAddress+phoneNumber;` At that moment all variables are null. Moreover the syntax for a query string is wrong. You will get a strange url. And you will serve them later with `getParams()`. Did you check if getParams() is called? For a GET request?

Comment: Yes I checked for GET request it still giving me the same error

Comment: Please I really need help with this problem it has driven me mad and it is not solving I tried like this "http://www.zamakpk.com/sos/index.php/webservices_api/insert‌​_user/1/2/3/4" then data is storing but only 1,2,3and 4 is the tables in database

Comment: greenapps yes in the error log the error is all variables are null so how can i pass them like it should be?

Comment: `Did you check if getParams() is called?`. You did not answer my question.

Comment: `yes in the error log the error is all variables are null ` Post the relevant lines from the logcat in a code block in your post. (not in a comment).

Comment: `so how can i pass them like it should be`. Well give a nice example first of your url containing a query string with your parameters and their values.

Comment: how should i know that if getparams () is called or not?

Comment: 11-02 09:33:11.615 30567-30958/? E/Volley: [254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://www.zamakpk.com/sos/index.php/webservices_api/insert_usernameaddressmobilemac. this is logcat message

Comment: i cant post more than two links in my account can't post logcat as i don't have 10 reputation

Comment: (so how can i pass them like it should be. Well give a nice example first of your url containing a query string with your parameters and their values.) i don't want to pass values in url i want to pass them dynamically

Comment: whatever user enter should be in my database just like that